# I am trying to change the order of english alphabets in a string such that for a it shall be z, for b it shall be y, etc.. and vice versa

Tags: c++, string, algorithm, for-loop, reverse

I am trying to replace each occurrence of the letter 'a' by the letter 'z', each occurrence of 'b' by 'y', etc, and each occurrence of 'z' by 'a'....in a string. But the code is not giving desired output...

```
int main()
{

    string S;
    cin >> S;
    string alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    string reversed = "zyxwvutsrqponmlkjihgfedcba";
    int N = S.length();

        for(int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        {
            for(int z = 0; z < 26; z++)
            {
                if(S[i] == alphabet[z])
                {
                    S[i] = reversed[z];
                }
            }
        }
        cout << S << endl;
}
```

Comment: Try following the execution with a debugger;

Comment: Consider the following scenario: You first replace "a" with "z". Then you continue looping through the rest of the letters, eventually replacing that same "z" with "a" again.

Comment: @AndyG okk understood

Comment: you can also do something like this btw `input[i] = 'z' - (input[i] - 'a');` no need for any additional strings

Comment: @Yamahari -- that works for ASCII encoded text, and for most other encodings, but it is not guaranteed to work for all possible encodings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my five cents.:)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cctype>
#include <cstring>

int main()
{
    const char alphabet[] = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    const size_t N = sizeof( alphabet ) - 1;

    std::string s( alphabet );

//  std::cin >> s;

    for (auto &c : s)
    {
        if (const char *p = std::strchr( alphabet, std::tolower( ( unsigned char )c ) ) )
        {
            size_t i = p - alphabet;

            if (std::isupper( c ))
            {
                c = std::toupper( alphabet[N - i - 1] );
            }
            else
            {
                c = alphabet[N - i - 1];
            }
        }
    }

    std::cout << alphabet << '\n';
    std::cout << s << '\n';
}
```

The program output is

```
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
zyxwvutsrqponmlkjihgfedcba
```

Pay attention to that the user can enter a symbol that is not present in the alphabet or a letter in the upper case. The program should correctly process such situations.

For example if the user will enter the string `"AbcxyZ"` then the program output will be

```
ZyxcbA
```

You could write a separate function that does the task. For example.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cctype>
#include <cstring>

std::string & reverse_letters( std::string &s )
{
    const char alphabet[] = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    const size_t N = sizeof( alphabet ) - 1;

    for (auto &c : s)
    {
        if (const char *p = std::strchr( alphabet, std::tolower( ( unsigned char )c ) ))
        {
            size_t i = p - alphabet;

            if (std::isupper( c ))
            {
                c = std::toupper( alphabet[N - i - 1] );
            }
            else
            {
                c = alphabet[N - i - 1];
            }
        }
    }

    return s;
}

int main()
{
    std::string s( "AbcxyZ" );

    std::cout << s << '\n';
    std::cout << reverse_letters( s ) << '\n';

    s.assign( "A1b2y3Z4" );

    std::cout << s << '\n';
    std::cout << reverse_letters( s ) << '\n';
}
```

The program output is

```
AbcxyZ
ZyxcbA
A1b2y3Z4
Z1y2b3A4
```

Answer (score 4):

If you're using ASCII you can do this:

```
int main()
{
    std::string S;
    std::cin >> S;
    std::for_each(std::execution::par_unseq, S.begin(), S.end(), 
                  [](char &c) { c = 'a' + 'z' - c; });
    std::cout << S << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: You may want to check if `c` is between 'a' and 'z'

Comment: range-based for would also work, no need for for_each

Answer (score 1):

Your logic is flawed:

```
 for(int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        {
            for(int z = 0; z < 26; z++)
            {
                if(S[i] == alphabet[z])
                {
                    S[i] = reversed[z];
                }
            }
        }
```

As `reversed` is the reversed of `alphabet`, whenever you encounter `S[i]== alphabet[z]` you will replace the letter, but after that you will encounter the replaced letter again in `alphabet`.

Example: You replace `a` by `z` but then at the end of the loop you find `z` and replace that by `a`.

To avoid replacing the replaced character, break from the loop after you replaced it:

```
 for(int i = 0; i < N; i++)
            {
                for(int z = 0; z < 26; z++)
                {
                    if(S[i] == alphabet[z])
                    {
                        S[i] = reversed[z];
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
```

Note that there is a more efficient solution, as characters `a` till `z` have consecutive values you can look them up directly instead of using a loop.

Moreover, you really should have used a debugger to see what the code does. It is simple code like this that is a good opportunity to learn how to use a debugger.